# Correct allocate and free memory for arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm dealing with  dynamic arrays. The function `empty_matrix()` creates a new array, representing a matrix. `delete_matrix()` frees all memory, allocated for the matrix.

Do I get a memory leak in function `example()` if I call `add(add(a, b), c)`? What will happen to the memory allocated in the function `add(...)`? Do I have to free it? Where should I do it?

```
 matrix empty_matrix(int dim) {
 matrix m;
 m.dim = dim;
 m.data = new int*[dim];
 for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
  m.data[i] = new int[dim];

 return m;
}

void delete_matrix(matrix m) {
 for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
  delete [] m.data[i];
 delete [] m.data;
}

matrix add(matrix a, matrix b) {
 matrix c = empty_matrix(a.dim);
 for (int i = 0; i < a.dim; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < a.dim; j++)
   c.data[i][j] = a.data[i][j] + b.data[i][j];

 return c;
}

void example() {
 matrix a = empty_matrix(100);
 matrix b = empty_matrix(100);
 matrix c = empty_matrix(100);

 // some modifications of a, b and c
 // ...

 matrix d = add(add(a, b), c);
 print_matrix(d);

 delete_matrix(a);
 delete_matrix(b);
 delete_matrix(c);
 delete_matrix(d);
}
```

Comment: You can use tools like valgrind: http://valgrind.org/ which can tell you are there leaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you **should** do is use Object Orientation/RAII. Your data member of matrix class should be private, and memory for it should be allocated in the constructor, and freed in the destructor. This way, you won't have to worry about memory leaks.

For example...

```
class matrix
{
public:
      typedef int element_type;
      matrix(int dimension)
          :data_(new element_type[dimension*dimension])
      {

      }  
      //Do define your copy-constructor and assignment operators
      ~matrix()
      {
         delete [] data_;
      } 

private:
      element_type* data_;
};
```

This all, of course, if this is homework. If it is not, then you should refrain from using arrays in this situation. Use `std::vector`s

Comment: With using Object orientation I can't avoid to free the Memory allocated by the `add(...)` function seperatly? Are `std::vector` s as fast as arrays? How do I access the data, via `get(int i, int j)`?

Comment: @multiholle: Yes, you will avoid the memory leak, because the temporary object will be destroyes, its destructor will be called and the memory will be freed. As to how to use vector see this link: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027

Comment: @multiholle: And yes, vectors are *almost* as fast as arrays. There are very few situations in which the difference is noticable.

Comment: What does this constructor mean? I don't know what's after the ":". <code>matrix(int dimension)
    :data_(new element_type[dimension*dimension])
{

}</code>

Comment: @multiholle: It's called constructor initialization list. Check this out http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Comment: I have tryed to implement it with a class matrix, but still have a memory leak: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4300663/519790 Using the destructor will cause a "Segmentation fault".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have to free the result of any `empty_matrix` or `add` call using `delete_matrix`. You're leaking memory, because you're not freeing the matrix of the innermost `add` call.

Answer (score 1):

You should have exactly one `new` for one `delete` and one `new[]` for one `delete[]` in your code. That's the most important principle.

Hence, if the function `add` creates a new matrix, it needs to be deleted somewhere.

---

Also, `empty_matrix` should be the constructor of the `matrix` class, and `delete_matrix` should be its destuctor.

You could also replace the `data` with a `std::vector` and your memory handling would be much more automated, relieving you from the necessity of counting `new`s and `delete`s.