# C++ - Efficiently computing a vector-matrix product

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I need to compute a product vector-matrix as efficiently as possible. Specifically, given a vector `s` and a matrix `A`, I need to compute `s * A`. I have a class `Vector` which wraps a `std::vector` and a class `Matrix` which also wraps a `std::vector` (for efficiency).

The naive approach (the one that I am using at the moment) is to have something like

```
Vector<T> timesMatrix(Matrix<T>& matrix)
{
    Vector<unsigned int> result(matrix.columns());
    // constructor that does a resize on the underlying std::vector

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < vector.size() ; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < matrix.columns() ; ++j)
        {
            result[j] += (vector[i] * matrix.getElementAt(i, j));
            // getElementAt accesses the appropriate entry
            // of the underlying std::vector
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works fine and takes nearly 12000 microseconds. Note that the vector `s` has 499 elements, while `A` is `499 x 15500`.

The next step was trying to parallelize the computation: if I have `N` threads then I can give each thread a part of the vector `s` and the "corresponding" rows of the matrix `A`. Each thread will compute a 499-sized `Vector` and the final result will be their entry-wise sum.
First of all, in the class `Matrix` I added a method to extract some rows from a `Matrix` and build a smaller one:

```
Matrix<T> extractSomeRows(unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
{
    unsigned int rowsToExtract = end - start + 1;
    std::vector<T> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(rowsToExtract * numColumns);
    for(unsigned int i = start * numColumns ; i < (end+1) * numColumns ; ++i)
    {
        tmp.push_back(matrix[i]);
    }
    return Matrix<T>(rowsToExtract, numColumns, tmp);
}
```

Then I defined a thread routine

```
void timesMatrixThreadRoutine
    (Matrix<T>& matrix, unsigned int start, unsigned int end, Vector<T>& newRow)
{
    // newRow is supposed to contain the partial result
    // computed by a thread
    newRow.resize(matrix.columns());
    for(unsigned int i = start ; i < end + 1 ; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < matrix.columns() ; ++j)
        {
            newRow[j] += vector[i] * matrix.getElementAt(i - start, j);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I modified the code of the `timesMatrix` method that I showed above:

```
Vector<T> timesMatrix(Matrix<T>& matrix)
{
    static const unsigned int NUM_THREADS = 4;
    unsigned int matRows = matrix.rows();
    unsigned int matColumns = matrix.columns();
    unsigned int rowsEachThread = vector.size()/NUM_THREADS;

    std::thread threads[NUM_THREADS];
    Vector<T> tmp[NUM_THREADS];

    unsigned int start, end;

    // all but the last thread
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS - 1 ; ++i)
    {
        start = i*rowsEachThread;
        end = (i+1)*rowsEachThread - 1;

        threads[i] = std::thread(&Vector<T>::timesMatrixThreadRoutine, this,
            matrix.extractSomeRows(start, end), start, end, std::ref(tmp[i]));
    }

    // last thread
    start = (NUM_THREADS-1)*rowsEachThread;
    end = matRows - 1;
    threads[NUM_THREADS - 1] = std::thread(&Vector<T>::timesMatrixThreadRoutine, this,
        matrix.extractSomeRows(start, end), start, end, std::ref(tmp[NUM_THREADS-1]));

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS ; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    Vector<unsigned int> result(matColumns);
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS ; ++i)
    {
        result = result + tmp[i];    // the operator+ is overloaded
    }

    return result;
}
```

It still works but now it takes nearly 30000 microseconds, which is almost three times as much as before.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you think there is a better approach?

---

### EDIT - using a "lightweight" `VirtualMatrix`

Following Ilya Ovodov's suggestion, I defined a class `VirtualMatrix` that wraps a `T* matrixData`, which is initialized in the constructor as

```
VirtualMatrix(Matrix<T>& m)
{
    numRows = m.rows();
    numColumns = m.columns();
    matrixData = m.pointerToData();
    // pointerToData() returns underlyingVector.data();
}
```

Then there is a method to retrieve a specific entry of the matrix:

```
inline T getElementAt(unsigned int row, unsigned int column)
{
    return *(matrixData + row*numColumns + column);
}
```

Now the execution time is better (approximately 8000 microseconds) but maybe there are some improvements to be made. In particular the thread routine is now

```
void timesMatrixThreadRoutine
    (VirtualMatrix<T>& matrix, unsigned int startRow, unsigned int endRow, Vector<T>& newRow)
{
    unsigned int matColumns = matrix.columns();
    newRow.resize(matColumns);
    for(unsigned int i = startRow ; i < endRow + 1 ; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < matColumns ; ++j)
        {
            newRow[j] += (vector[i] * matrix.getElementAt(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

and the really slow part is the one with the nested `for` loops. If I remove it, the result is obviously wrong but is "computed" in less than 500 microseconds. This to say that now passing the arguments takes almost no time and the heavy part is really the computation.

According to you, is there any way to make it even faster?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you make a partial copy of matrix for each thread in extractSomeRows. It takes a lot of time.
Redesign it so that "some rows" become virtual matrix pointing at data located in original matrix.

Comment: Moreover it seems that you copy matrix data twice (1st time into std::vector<T> tmp then into matrix)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: that would be interesting to try. Now my question is "how can I implement a virtual matrix?"

Comment: If Matrix stores its data in vector, then implementation of matrix.getElementAt(i, j) is somthing like *(vector.data() + rowcount*i + j).

Comment: Right now I have `return matrix[row*numColumns + column]` where `matrix` is the name of the `std::vector` that stores all the elements. I can try with `data()` to see if it's faster

Comment: If Matrix stores its data in vector, then implementation of matrix.getElementAt(i, j) is somthing like return *(vector.data() + column_count*i + j). Create class VirtualMatrix, initialize it with reference to main matrix vector.data(). Then its getElementAt(i, j) must be implemented as *(vector.data() + column_count*(i + start_row) + j).

Answer (score 1):

Use vectorized assembly instructions for an architecture by making it more explicit that you want to multiply in 4's, i.e. for the x86-64 SSE2+ and possibly ARM'S NEON.

C++ compilers can often unroll the loop into vectorized code if you explicitly make an operation happen in contingent elements:

[Simple and fast matrix-vector multiplication in C / C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289235/simple-and-fast-matrix-vector-multiplication-in-c-c)

There is also the option of using libraries specifically made for matrix multipication. For larger matrices, it may be more efficient to use special implementations based on the Fast Fourier Transform, alternate algorithms like Strassen's Algorithm, etc. In fact, your best bet would be to use a C library like this, and then wrap it in an interface that looks similar to a C++ vector.

Comment: I tried unrolling by hand four operations but the execution time did not change. I admit I know pretty much nothing about FFT techniques, so I will try to read up a bit and see what I can find.