# How to multiply two integer square matrices using MSVC inline assembly in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, matrix-multiplication, inline-assembly

I wrote this code in C++ with inline assembly _asm for square matrix multiplication.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 2;
    int A[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    int B[2][2] = { {5, 6}, {7, 8} };
    int C[2][2] = { {0, 0}, {0, 0} };
    _asm {
        mov ecx, n
        lea esi, A
        lea edi, B
        lea edx, C
        outer_loop :
            push ecx
            mov ecx, n
            inner_loop :
                push ecx
                mov eax, [esi] ; load A[i][k]
                mov ebx, [edi] ; load B[k][j]
                imul eax, ebx ; compute A[i][k] * B[k][j]
                add [edx], eax ; accumulate result in C[i][j]
                add esi, 4 ; increment A pointer
                add edi, 4 ; increment B pointer
                add edx, 4 ; increment C pointer
                pop ecx
                loop inner_loop ; repeat for all k
            add esi, 400 ; jump to next row of A
            sub esi, ecx ; adjust A pointer
            mov eax, ecx
            imul eax, 4
            sub eax, n
            imul eax, 4
            lea edi, [edi + eax] ; jump to next column of B
            pop ecx
            loop outer_loop ; repeat for all i
    }
    cout << "Resultant matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << C[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn’t give any errors, but the resultant matrix C isn’t correct. It gives me these elements

```
5 12
0 0
```

I tried to change the offsets, but it didn't help.

Comment: At least you have to add `400` (the size of one row: `4 * 100`) to the pointers instead of `4` or `m` to move to next row. Also simple typical implementation of matrix multiplication will have 3 nested loops, but your code looks having only 2.

Comment: @MikeCAT I tried a lot, but nothing worked. Can you please tell me how to fix the code and how to add the third loop that you talked about

Comment: In order to implement matrix multiplication `A*B`, the elements of `A` are traversed rowwise, while the elements of `B` are traversed columnwise.

Comment: @Hari I know, but what to do please in the code?

Comment: I would recommend leaving this to the compiler. It can do a much better job(for the mos part) than we can in writing assembly. Do profiling and see if writing it in c++ is a problem or not. Looks like micro-optimization to me?

Comment: @user12002570 I know that the compiler is better for sure, but it's necessary for me now to do that using inline assembly for my project.

Comment: @Markmorlin Have you tried looking at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8We8EoK5j)

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, for sure, but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: I will describe the 3 loops that MikeCAT is referring to. The innermost loop multiplies and accumulates the row `i` of `A` and column `j` of `B` to compute the value of `C[i][j]`. The middle loop is either over the rows of `A` or columns of `B` (depending on which is more cache efficient). The outermost loop is over the rows of `A` or columns of `B`, depending on what was chosen for the middle loop.

Comment: @Hari, I know and understand that, but I couldn't implement this within the inline assembly.

Comment: You can make clang compile without vectorization to get code similar to yours : https://godbolt.org/z/rxf1zc5q5 (maybe you can spot some differences yourself). Looks like that code jumps out of the loop at the beginning at least it does what I expect and doesn't use the loop instruction.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I tried that, but it didn't help either.

Comment: I would say it would help, because you have an example of something that works. Oh... or did you mean you tried jnz, or jge instead of loop?

Comment: What I notice most is that the compiler doesn't even try to use ecx as a loop counter. It just stores three loop variables on the stack. Avoids all the push/pops of ecx . I wouldn't worry too much about the performance difference of that (considering this is slow assembly for modern processors anyway)

Comment: Yes, I tried that also

Comment: @PepijnKramer: You forgot to enable any optimization options; that asm is total garbage.  https://godbolt.org/z/xzhdndsnx is what I commented on the OP's last version of the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093915/how-to-write-a-program-for-matrix-multiplication-in-c-with-inline-assembly), with clang `-O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -m32 -Wall -fno-unroll-loops -fno-tree-vectorize` to make loops that could be used in MSVC inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unfortunately, neither helped.

Comment: People have already pointed out the most important bug in your code: it only has two nested loops.  Matmul needs to do O(N^3) work: every element of the result is a dot-product of a row of one input and a column of the other.  The C++ in my Godbolt link does it that way.  Another way to do it is shown in [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714514) - adding to a different element of the destination in every iteration of the inner loop, but with contiguous access to the inputs and outputs.

Comment: `push ecx` / `pop ecx` inside the inner loop is unnecessary in your code: nothing modifies ECX between those instructions so your program would run the same if you removed them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple variant based on your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 2;
    int A[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    int B[2][2] = { {5, 6}, {7, 8} };
    int C[2][2] = { {0, 0}, {0, 0} };
    _asm {
            ; note that two dimensional arrays are laid out
            ; contiguously in memory, that means that it is
            ; possible to iterate through it by the pointer
            ; incremention in this order A[R0][C0] .. A[R0][CN] .. A[RN][C0] ..A[RN][CN],
            ; from this you can evaluate that pointer to A[k][n] (A + k * n + n) is equal
            ; to the poinrt of A[k+1][0] (A + (k + 1) * n + 0)

            lea esi, A;        set A pointer to &A[0][0]
            lea edx, C;        set C pointer to &C[0][0]
            mov ecx, n

idx_loop :  push ecx
            lea edi, B;         set B pointer to &B[0][0]
            mov ecx, n

kdx_loop :  push ecx
            lea ecx, [edx+8];   set ecx to &C[i][n] for cmp usage
            mov ebx, [esi];     load A[i][k]

jdx_loop :  mov eax, [edi];     load B[k][j]
            imul eax, ebx;      compute A[i][k] * B[k][j]
            add[edx], eax;      accumulate result in C[i][j]
            add edi, 4;         set B pointer to &B[k][j+1]
            add edx, 4;         set C pointer to &C[i][j+1]
            cmp ecx, edx
            jne jdx_loop;       repeat for all j - j++

            add esi, 4;         set A pointer to &A[i][k+1]
            mov ebx, edx;       save &C[i][n]
            lea edx, [ebx-8];   set C pointer to &C[i][0]
            pop ecx;
            loop kdx_loop;      repeat for all k - k++

            mov edx, ebx;       set C pointer to &C[i][0]
            pop ecx
            loop idx_loop;      repeat for all i - i++
    }
    cout << "Resultant matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << C[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300663/how-to-speed-up-matrix-multiplication-in-c) to get, why the order of cycles is swapped.

Comment: `A[i][k]` is loop-invariant in the inner loop with this nesting; you could hoist that load since you're already spending two registers (EAX and EBX) on separate loads instead of load + memory-source `imul`.

Comment: Also, `loop` is a [slow way to write loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently): you could compute the next-row pointer in ECX and `cmp edi, ecx` / `jne jdx_loop` and use `mov edi, ecx` to make the inner-most loop more efficient.  (Or just a comment since `edi` loops over the whole `B[][]`, it doesn't need resetting the way the other pointers do, although for consistency / readability there should at least be a comment about how `B[k+1][0]` starts at the same address we ended at, `B[k][n]`)

Comment: @Peter Cordes thanks for your remarks, i've updated the code accordingly. i hope, the comments now are more clear.

Comment: I think that's an improvement.  It is for performance of the inner loop on Intel CPUs, where `loop` is slow.  But you're still loading the same value from `[esi]` inside the loop every time, and you're not using EBX for anything.  The first 2 instructions of the loop could be `mov eax, [edi]` / `imul eax, ebx`, with a `mov ebx, [esi]` outside the loop.  That doesn't help with front-end throughput, but is faster on SnB/IvB and Zen 1/2 which can only do 2 address calculations per clock (including stores): https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html#total-accesses-limit

Comment: Although the loop is 7 uops, so it's not going to run at 1/clock even on Alder Lake.  But it's generally better to hoist loads if you have a spare register, and for human readers emphasizes the point that that value is loop-invariant.

Comment: With the explicit comments like `put &B[0][0] to stack`, that instruction should just be `lea edi, B`.  Also, `mov ecx, edx` / `add ecx, 8` should be `lea ecx, [edx+8]`.  It actually is an address so it's not "tricky".  But in general try to use LEA to copy-and-add if you ever want a sum in a different register from the input(s).

Comment: @Peter Cordes thanks for remarks with details! updated the code, also it seems it is possible to drop evaluation of C[i+1] and stask push for this, by moving `ecx` to the free register, will update the code later.

Comment: replaced push on the stack of the C pointer by moving the value from EBX